# How to properly use MediaPlayer as notification?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Actually i'm developing an app for an Android Device with a barcode scanner and i'm trying to set a .wav sound that should be played every time i've read the same barcode.

on my scan method i'm simply trying to do the following:

```
MediaPlayer mpFound = MediaPlayer.create(OrdiniActivity.this, R.raw.exist);
            mpFound.start();
```

this sound can be stuck with another that i start every time the scanner scanned a barcode that exist in a history list but the issue is that if i read multiple barcodes (so the code above is run more and more times)  the sound just die and doesn't sound any sound anymore.

Comment: You will have to request audio permission before playing the sound.

Comment: @RishabhSagar actually MediaPlayer doesn't need permission in manifest, and actually the sound works but just die after i call the code in the question more and more times

Comment: Try to set mpFound as a global variable and allocate it in the OnCreate method of your activity

Comment: @IgorMytyuk , Sorry, my bad. I mean, did you request audio focus before playing sound?

Comment: i think for short audio you should use SoundPool

Comment: @RishabhSagar i just use the code in the question to play sound, how should i request focus?